# Set value for AttachedProperty with own type

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, attached-properties

I have created a class like

```
public class ContextMenuSetting {
    public bool ContextMenuAllowed { get; set; }
    public string GridKey { get; set; }
}
```

And a AttachedProperty like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuSettingsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContextMenuSettings", typeof(ContextMenuSetting), typeof(BarItemLink), null);

public static void SetContextMenuSettings(this BarItemLink target, ContextMenuSetting contextMenuSetting) {
    target.SetValue(ContextMenuSettingsProperty, contextMenuSetting);
}

public static ContextMenuSetting GetContextMenuSettings(this DependencyObject target) {
    return (ContextMenuSetting)target.GetValue(ContextMenuSettingsProperty);
}
```

I have now the following use of BarItemLink in xaml:

```
<dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="newActivity"  />
```

Can somebody help me, how I can set now a Value for the AttachedProperty ContextMenuSettings for BarButtonLink?

**edit - update solution:**

With Charleh's help, i have found the solution:

```
<dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="newActivity">
   <pcce:BarItemLinkExtensions.ContextMenuSettings >
       <pcce:ContextMenuSettings ContextMenuAllowed="True" GridKey="hallo"/>
   </pcce:BarItemLinkExtensions.ContextMenuSettings>
</dxb:BarItemLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the ContextMenuSetting classes namespace in the XAML?

```
xmlns:ctxmenu="SomeNameSpace"

<dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="blah" ctxmenu:ContextMenuSetting.ContextMenuSettings="blah" />
```

Edit: if you want to set a custom type you can use either a TypeConverter (if you want to enter a string value) or use the extended syntax

```
<dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="blah">
   <ctxMenu:ContextMenuSetting.ContextMenuSettings SomeProperty="SomeValue" />
</dxb:BarItemLink>
```

Or TypeConverter if you want to do this:

```
<dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="blah" ctxmenu:ContextMenuSetting.ContextMenuSettings="blah" />
```

Which will interpret the string value "blah" and use a TypeConverter to create the proper type in code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx

Comment: Yes. But the attached property is ContextMenuSettings and the class of the object is ContextMenuSetting. Now, how can I set a value of type ContextMenuSetting to the AttachedProperty ContextMenuSettings?

Comment: Thank you. With your help, I have found the solution. I have edited my question with the solution.